# Comma in front of square bracket - MDN docs

Tags: javascript

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) is my primary Javascript resource.
I often see a notation like `( currentValue[, index[, array]])` as in:

```js
let new_array = arr.map(function callback( currentValue[, index[, array]]) {
    // return element for new_array
}[, thisArg])
```

I'm surprised there's a square bracket in front of the comma. It looks like an invalid syntax to me.

I would highly appreciate it if somebody could give more information about this notation.

Comment: It is just a sign to show that those are optional except the currentValue

Comment: This notation is not Javascript syntax itself, it is a notation to *describe* Javascript syntax. Similar to BNF (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form), maybe there is a formal definition of that notation somewhere on MDN as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The square brackets mean that the enclosed parameter is optional.

Refer [MDN syntax section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/Contribute/Structures/Syntax_sections) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

That means the callback requires a currentValue as the first argument, and index and array are optional arguments.

Answer (score 0):

It is an invalid JS syntax, and it would throw an error.

However, it is used to denote optional arguments as a pseudo-code.

The parts in the square brackets are considered optional (and in the real code the brackets should be omitted), so, you might call this function like:

```js
let new_array = arr.map(function callback(currentValue) {
    // return element for new_array
})
//or
let new_array = arr.map(function callback(currentValue) {
    // return element for new_array
}, thisArg)
//or
let new_array = arr.map(function callback(currentValue, index) {
    // return element for new_array
})
//or
let new_array = arr.map(function callback(currentValue, index) {
    // return element for new_array
}, thisArg)
//or
let new_array = arr.map(function callback(currentValue, index, array) {
    // return element for new_array
})
//or
let new_array = arr.map(function callback(currentValue, index, array) {
    // return element for new_array
}, thisArg)
```

and each of them is valid.